# Como fazer uma pesquisa com limitação de período com o datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho um campo `data_inicio` e um campo `data_fim`. Preciso usar o `datepicker` nos dois.

Quero que, quando eu selecionar a data `data_inicio`, o campo `data_fim` fique afetada, de maneira que somente datas posteriores de `data_inicio` sejam exibidas. E, se selecionar primeiro o `data_fim`, o campo `data_inicio` tenha uma data máxima em relação a data selecionada no `data_fim`.

Como fazer isso no jQuery UI?

[image: Input com datepicker]

Comment: na própria documentação já tem um exemplo, da uma olhada. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Mas agora temos um exemplo em português :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir as opções `minDate` e o `maxDate` para fazer isso:

```js
$(function () {
  var data = {};
  data.inicio = $("#data_inicio");
  data.fim = $("#data_fim");
  
  data.inicio.datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
      data.fim.datepicker("option", "minDate", data.inicio.datepicker("getDate"));      
    }
  });  
  data.fim.datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
      data.inicio.datepicker("option", "maxDate", data.fim.datepicker("getDate"));      
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="data_inicio" type="text" />
<input id="data_fim" type="text" />
```